# IdentityServer 4 Scope related users (login with user in specific scope)

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver4, .net-6.0, abp

Hello im using IdentityServer 4
I have a back-office and mobile app both with separate IdentityServer clients and scopes

back-office users use
`CarSharing_Web` client with `CarSharing` API scope and API resources

Mobile app users use
`CarSharing_WeRent` client with `WeRent` API scope and API resources

What I want is if you want to get access token on `CarSharing_WeRent` client you can only get it with user registered with `CarSharing_WeRent` client

I don't want the back-office users to login to mible with back-office account

on mobile I'm using `/connect/token` api

this is my request on post man
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would not modify the token exchange flow, what I would do is make sure that the `WeRent` API scope is only authorized for users authenticated using the `CarSharing_WeRent` client id.

*IdentityServer4* adds a claim for the client id used to authenticate the request, the claim is called `client_id`. You can create an authorization policy that checks for that claim with the correct value and attach it to your `WeRent` controller.

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("WeRent", policy => {
        policy.RequireClaim("client_id", "CarSharing_WeRent");
    });
});
```

And use this on the controller:

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "WeRent")]
public class WeRentController : ControllerBase {
...
```